# SAS - replacing a character with a space?

Tags: regex, string, text, sas

Had a quick question - I need to remove punctuation and replace characters with a space (i.e.: if I have a field that contains a * I need to replace it with a white space).

I can't seem to get it right - I was originally doing this to just remove it, but I've found that in some cases my string is being squished together.

Thoughts?

```
STRING2 = compress(STRING, ":,*~’°-!';()®""@#$%^&©+=\/|[]}{]{?><ÉÑËÁ’ÍÓÄö‘—È…...");
```

Answer (score 3):

The `COMPRESS()` function will remove the characters. If you want to replace them with spaces then use the `TRANSLATE()` function. If you want to reduce multiple blanks to a single blank use the `COMPBL()` function.

```
STRING2 = compbl(translate(STRING,' ',":,*~’°-!';()®""@#$%^&©+=\/|[]}{]{?><ÉÑËÁ’ÍÓÄö‘—È…..."));
```

Rather than listing the characters that need to be converted to spaces you could use `COMPRESS()` to turn the problem around to listing the characters that should be kept.

So this example will use the modifiers `ad` on the `COMPRESS()` function call to pass the characters in STRING that are not alphanumeric characters to the `TRANSLATE()` function call so they will be replaced by spaces.

```
STRING2 = compbl(translate(STRING,' ',compress(STRING,' ','ad')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the translate function and see if it fits your needs:

```
data want;
STRING = "!';AAAAÄAA$";
STRING2 = translate(STRING,' ',':;,*~''’°-!()®@""#$%^&©+=\/|[]}{]{?><ÉÑËÁ’ÍÓÄö‘—È…...');
run;
```

Output:

```
STRING         STRING2

!';AAAAÄAA$ AAAA AA
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `TRANSLATE()` function.

TRANSLATE(SOURCE,TO,FROM);

```
data test;
string = "1:,*2~’°-ÍÓ3Äö‘—È…...4";
string2 = translate(string,
   "                                                    ",
   ":,*~’°-!';()®""@#$%^&©+=\/|[]}{]{?><ÉÑËÁ’ÍÓÄö‘—È…...");
put string2=;
run;
```

I get

```
string2=1   2      3         4
```

Answer (score 0):

While translate function could get you there, you could also use REGEX in SAS. It is more elegant, but you need to escape the characters in the actual regex pattern.

```
data want; 
   input string $60.; 
   length new_string $60.; 
   new_string = prxchange('s/([\:\,\*\~\’\°\-\!\'||"\'"||';\(\)\®\"\"\@\#\$\%\^\&\©\+\=\\\/\|\[\}\{\]\{\\\?\>\<\É\Ñ\Ë\Á\’\Í\Ó\Ä\ö\‘\—\È\…\.\.\.\]])/ /',-1,string); 
   datalines; 
Cats, dogs, and anyone else!
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the help of regular expressions.
data have;
  old = "AM;'IGH}|GH";
  new = prxchange("s/[^A-Z]/ /",-1,old);
run; 
proc print data=have nobs;
run;

OUTPUT-
        old            new

```
 AM;'IGH}|GH    AM  IGH  GH
```